# Kafka Console Producer - Error when sending message to topic : TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a Confluent Platform Kafka Cluster with 3 nodes and everything seems to work fine but when product some message with the console, get the error!

command :

```
/opt/kafka/confluent-4.0.0/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list  109.169.xxx.xxx:9092 --topic sh
```

error :

```
ERROR Error when sending message to topic sh with key: null, value: 1 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback) org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for sh-1: 1538 ms has passed since batch creation plus linger time
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  I'm assuming you resolved this issue since you posted it over a year ago.

Comment: I recommend not using `CLI` and write a `Producer` or `Consumer` using `python` or `java` for testing.

Comment: The CLI is just to test it.  I'm having the same problem publishing to a topic from NiFi.

Answer (score 1):

You can get this error with high latency connections (see you have 1.5s passing). The CLI works fine and would be "better" than writing the same simple thing in Java because the CLI is just a Java wrapper anyway. Python or kafkacat would be less verbose, sure

The default batch size of the console producer is 200 records, last time I looked, so if you are sending data less than this, then the batch will eventually expire